# VSCode tasks.json and launch.json for WinExe dependent on dll

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I'm trying - for the sake of learning - to write tasks.json & launch.json for VSCode to build this project: [ExportableDataGrid](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-s-z/tree/master/WPF%20Exporting%20Data%20from%20a%20DataGrid%20Control/%5BC%23%5D-WPF%20Exporting%20Data%20from%20a%20DataGrid%20Control/C%23)

There are two .csproj - one builds a 'Library' and the other a 'WinExe' which depends on the library.

The build is successful, but the Debugger doesn't launch the .exe and has this error:

```
Error processing 'configurationDone' request. Unknown Error: 0x80131c30
```

With this cli:

```
dotnet build Mm.ExportableDataGrid\Mm.ExportableDataGrid.csproj
dotnet build Mm.ExportableDataGrid.Wpf\Mm.ExportableDataGrid.Wpf.csproj
```

I get these errors:

```
CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [C:\Users\userid\C-Sharp Projects\ExportableDataGrid\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf.csf.csproj]
C:\Users\userid\C-Sharp Projects\ExportableDataGrid\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf\MainWindow.xaml.cs(13,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\userid\C-Sharp Projects\ExportableDataGrid\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf.csproj]
C:\Users\userid\C-Sharp Projects\ExportableDataGrid\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf\MainWindow.xaml.cs(52,13): error CS0103: The name 'dataGrid' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\userid\C-Sharp Prp Projects\ExportableDataGrid\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf\mm.exportabledatagrid.wpf.csproj]
```

Both launch.json and tasks.json are in a root folder containing both folders from the github archive.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Custom .NET Launcher",
            "type": "clr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "buildExe",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Mm.ExportableDataGrid.Wpf/bin/Debug/Mm.ExportableDataGrid.Wpf.exe",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label":"buildDll",
            "type":"shell",
            "command":"C:/\"Program Files (x86)/\"Microsoft Visual Studio\"/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe",
            "presentation":{
                "clear":true
                },
            "args":[
                "Mm.ExportableDataGrid\\Mm.ExportableDataGrid.csproj",
                "/t:Build",
                "/p:Configuration=Debug",
                "/p:Platform=\"AnyCPU\""
            ]
        },
        {
            "label":"buildExe",
            "type":"shell",
            "command":"C:/\"Program Files (x86)/\"Microsoft Visual Studio\"/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe",
            "presentation":{
                "clear":true
                },
            "dependsOn":"buildDll",
            "args":[
                "Mm.ExportableDataGrid.Wpf\\Mm.ExportableDataGrid.Wpf.csproj",
                "/t:Build",
                "/p:Configuration=Debug",
                "/p:Platform=\"AnyCPU\""
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Despite much reading I cannot figure out what is going on here.

1. How do I debug the 0x80131c30 error?
2. Why do I get the CS5001 error?

Also - I am able to Run Without Debugging, no issues. Seems to be an issue with attaching the debugger.

Comment: there is no task `buildExe`

Comment: My bad, there is but I accidentally cut it out of the post. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the issue after weeks having trouble with it.

The fix is to create a "My_Project.runsettings" file specifying "x64" and refer to it in the settings.json of you solution with "omnisharp.testRunSettings":"Path_To_My_File\My_Project.runsettings"

Please see my answer on github for the detailed explanation : https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4361#issuecomment-858540496